Google Form to spreadsheet script | no event object or values found ERROR
function onFormSubmitRoofing(e) {
Logger.log('Event object: ' + JSON.stringify(e)); // Log the event object
 
if (!e || !e.values) {
 Logger.log("No event object or values found.");
 return; // Exit the function if there are no values
  }

Logger.log('Form submitted: ' + JSON.stringify(e.values)); // Log the form data

// Update this to your sheet ID and name
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1QpOZxLNWd21eYpcOk_gQfTE9aD0BRRlF7resFcOECec').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var targetRow = 61; // Start at row 61
var startColumn = 6; // Column F is the 6th column

 Set the values to the specified row starting from column F
 sheet.getRange(targetRow, startColumn, 1, e.values.length).setValues([e.values]);
 Logger.log('Data written to sheet: ' + JSON.stringify(e.values)); // Log successful write
}


 function testOnFormSubmitRoofing() {
  var e = {
  values: ["Test Name"] // Simulated submission
   };
 onFormSubmitRoofing(e);
 }

I have this function where i am submitting a google form and i want it to return to a specific row in and column in spreadsheet. I've created a trigger in apps script where the event is from form -on form submit.  trigger every time i submit a form, nothing populates in the google spreadsheet. When I run the function testOnFormSubmitRoofing, it sends the "test name" to the correct spot. this is the results i keep getting when i check the executions log in apps script after submitting a form. linking the forms is just not possible due to some other codes written.










Aug 25, 2024, 8:44:20 PM
Info
Event object: {"authMode":"FULL","response":{},"source":{},"triggerUid":"229403691"}


Aug 25, 2024, 8:44:20 PM
Info
No event object or values found.



i've tried everything, deleting the trigger and re-adding it, creating a new form, sending the form to a different spreadsheet. same exact error everytime. any solution?

Use code fences to format your code. Test formatting before posting questions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you create the trigger for the form or the spreadsheet.  It's looking like you created it for the form. I'm not sure what the truthiness is for an array why not use e.values.length instead.  You should always get an e.values because values[0] is always a timestamp.  My guess is that you are using the wrong trigger.

Based on the details in the image in the question, your Apps Script is bound to Google Forms. In this case, the form submit event doesn't have the values property. This property is included in the Apps Script project and is bound to a spreadsheet.
Considering the above, if you want to use the values property, you must create a project bound to the spreadsheet linked to the form. Don't forget to delete the trigger created in the project bound to the Google Form to avoid wasting the daily total execution time quota by a non-working trigger.

Submitting a google form into Spreadsheet
It looks like you are submitting a google form and you want it to return to a specific row and column in spreadsheet.
Sample Output

Executions screenshot:

Script used:
function onFormSubmitRoofing(e) { 
  Logger.log('Event object: ' + JSON.stringify(e)); // Log the event object

if (!e || !e.values) { 
  Logger.log("No event object or values found."); 
  return; // Exit the function if there are no values 
  }

Logger.log('Form submitted: ' + JSON.stringify(e.values)); // Log the form data

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1loS7IjRbUd71dLnatzI5MBOTzjjZJsItXz8z-uB-eqU').getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'); 
var targetRow = 61; // Start at row 61 
var startColumn = 6; // Column F is the 6th column

//Set the values to the specified row starting from column F 
sheet.getRange(targetRow, startColumn, 1, e.values.length).setValues([e.values]); 
Logger.log('Data written to sheet: ' + JSON.stringify(e.values)); 
// Log successful write 
}

function testOnFormSubmitRoofing() { 
  var e = { values: ["Test Name"] // Simulated submission 
  }; onFormSubmitRoofing(e); 
}

I've retested your code multiple times and haven't seen any errors. Try using the script above.
REFERENCE:
Event Objects

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
